# C language and shared memory

Tags: c, shared-memory

How to memory segment pointer copy file type pointer data.
like this

`ptr` is a pointer which is attach to memory segment which we created. and `fp` is file pointer .By using `fp=fopen("file name",w+(mode));`. and i have to write something inside `fp`  like this.

```
fprintf(fp,"hello vishnu");
```

By using shared memory I want to send this server end.

How is it possible to do this? How can I take this data at server end?

Comment: You want to use a `FILE*` to send stuff from one process to another? The answer is going to be platform-specific, and you haven't specified a platform. Andrey has given you a Windows mechanism, but the answer will be different for POSIX or other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

To share memory between processes you can use [File Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Sir,i can not use File Mapping, without file mapping it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pipe` or an `AF_UNIX` socket.

Either effectively gives you a shared memory segment with file descriptor access. You can use `fdopen` to connect that file descriptor to the `FILE*` you want.

The difference is that `pipe` creates an anonymous pipe, and gives you a file descriptor for each end, in a single process. The only (easy) way to use this for IPC is to do it in a parent process, and then fork/exec the child so it inherits one end of the pipe.

The `AF_UNIX` socket is named by the filesystem, so two independent processes can connect using a known path name.

Note that both of these are related to shared memory only by implementation details: you can't get direct access to the shared memory segment, but rely on the OS.